# Sitecore data into HTML through REST calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sitecore

How to expose Sitecore field data into HTML page using Javascript, AngularJS and  RESTful web service calls?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>List of Sales Engineers</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/myangular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="CallWebApi">
        <ul>
            <li ng:repeat="item in data.result.items">{{item.DisplayName}}</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript to make the call and return the Sitecore items:

```
function CallWebApi($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('**Sitecore URL**').
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            console.log('success ' + data)
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('failure ' + data)
        });
```

What Sitecore URL do i have to pick to make a call?

Comment: This sounds like some sort of test question. If you are referring to the actual URL for the Get method, then only you know the answer, as you don't provide any information on possible API endpoints...

Comment: do u think this question is valid? If so please update it as needed.. two three lines will not be enough to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of functionality you can use :

1. For Sitecore 7.2 or older release you can use Sitecore Web API . In Sitecore 7.2 it was integrated with  the release and  before it was a standalone module.
2. For Sitecore 7.5 or new versions you can use Sitecore Services Client.
   https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/what-is-sitecore-services-client/

   Please read [Sitecore Developer Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf)